# Why might a (Java) program fail in one function when the active window is minimized in Windows?

Tags: java, windows

I have an annoying issue with a commercial Java-based program I use.

The program is a trading workstation (TWS, Interactive  Brokers). When I minimize the program window to the Windows (7) taskbar, the application no longer transmits a feed of information to a custom application I have written (compiled C++) that connects with (TWS) via a socket. The TWS program does not crash when minimized, and when I restore the window the data feed to my app resumes.

The problem  is not intermittent- the data feed stops the instant the window is minimized, and resumes the instant it is restored, every time. I can focus on other windows and not lose the feed- it is specific to minimization. And my app does not "disconnect" with the TWS- the app generates error messages related to loss of the market data feed but does not ever claim to be disconnected, something it would know instantly.

I've gone thru every config in the program TWS. I've also spoken with IB and, surprisingly, the person there could not help me. I googled search terms around this problem and I did find one guy who had a problem with his iTunes playback skipping when the iTunes window was minimized.

Are there any settings at the level of the CPU/OS or Java that I can try here?

My PC is capable and has a quad-core CPU, so Affinity would not appear to matter/help.

Comment: Is there any event handler code for the minimized state of your window?

Comment: Afzaal, thank you. My own app, which listens to the data feed from the TWS, is written (in C+) using an API where there can be two "sources" of the (same) feed, the TWS app I have a problem with and a streamlined app (called "IB Gateway," also in Java), chosen based solely on my changing the listening port number and no other code. When I change the port number and use the IBG instead, I can minimize the IBG window without losing the feed. So, it seems specific to TWS, which I do not have the source code for.

Comment: OK, thinking about your reply, it sounds like my question is probably rhetorical, as the TWS program was likely written to do this rather than the behavior being an outcome based on Windows and/or Java management of resources.

Comment: Possible workaround: run TWS (and, if necessary, something to relay the data) in a virtual machine, you can then minimize the virtual machine without affecting TWS.

Comment: Harry, that is a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer, but might be useful

```
void importantFoo() {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            ..... // do stuff
            System.out.println(((java.awt.Window) myWindowOrFrame).getOwnedWindows()[0].isFocused() ? "" : "window focus lost...");
        }
    });
}
```